# errors in extracting json object

Tags: java, android, json

I have to retrieve json object from json file from this [url](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week).

My code is throwing java.lang.RuntimeException in doInBackground() and string to jsonObject conversion exception. 
Can anyone help me at this? I am new to Android programming.

```
package course.examples.networkingearthquake;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;

public class HttpActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView mTextView;
EditText etInput;
TextView input;
String number;//edited
int num;//edited
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_socket);

        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        input = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.input);
        etInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        input.setText("Input");

        //number = etInput.getText().toS();

        final Button btDisplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btDisplay);
        btDisplay.setText("DISPLAY");

        btDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v) {

                new HttpGetTask().execute();

               }
        });
  }


private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

       private static final String TAG = "HttpGetTask";
       private static final String URL = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week";

       AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");                                           

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(Void... params){

           HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
           JSONResponseHandler responseHandler = new JSONResponseHandler();
          // ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

           try{

               return mClient.execute(request,responseHandler);

           }catch(ClientProtocolException exception){
             exception.printStackTrace();
           }catch(IOException exception){
              exception.printStackTrace(); 
           }
            return null;
           }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result){
          if(null != mClient)
              mClient.close();
          mTextView.setText(result);
      }

   }
private class JSONResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<String>{


    @Override
    public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = null;
        String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
        JSONResponse = JSONResponse.substring(17, JSONResponse.length()-3);
        num = Integer.parseInt(number);// edited
        try {
            JSONObject responseObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(
                    JSONResponse).nextValue();
            JSONArray features = responseObject.getJSONArray("features");
            JSONObject retObject = (JSONObject)features.get(num);//edited
        //  JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject)retObject.get("geometry");

            result  = retObject.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When debugging with invalid JSON exceptions, I highly suggest printing to the console/log at different times to see what the String of characters you're working with actually looks like. That way you can be sure you are working with valid JSON at all steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned by the URL you specify containts eqfeed_callback() which needs to be stripped in order to make it valid JSON.

It seems like you have done this in your response handler, but you are cutting off one character too much at both the start and the end.

Try this:

```
JSONResponse = JSONResponse.substring(16, JSONResponse.length()-2);
```

Comment: thanks. I was doing the mistake you pointed out and now it is running :)

Comment: Ihave edited my code and marked the lines with comment "edited". I want to convert the edittext string into integer but it is throwing NumberFormatException. Can you help me at this as well.

Comment: num = Integer.parseInt(etInput.getText().toString()); should work fine. 
Are you sure you are only inputting numbers?

Comment: yup i am sure . I have resolved that earlier only. but thanks for your for help.